# duplicate value's in another table

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables: table1 and table2.

I have a .csv file which contains a lot of duplicates and I place them in table2. So I have a clean table1 with no duplicates and another table with all the duplicates from table1. How can I do this? I have this code which only places the .csv file into table1 (with duplicates):

I have placed the values in an array this works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (aanhef,achternaam,email,bedrag) 
VALUES('$aanhef','$achternaam','$email','$bedrag')";

mysql_query($sql); "
```

Comment: Why don't you clean table for duplicate rows by sql. Then there is no need to transfer data.

Comment: So to be clear you want to get the unique values from csv to one table and the duplicate values to another table right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=file_get_contents('testing.csv');

$data=explode(',',$data);

$uniqueValues = array_unique($data);
$duplicateValues = array_diff_assoc($data, $uniqueValues);
print_r($uniqueValues);
echo '</br>';
print_r($duplicateValues);
```

This code splits a csv file into 2 `arrays`, the ones which have the duplicates and the ones that have only unique values as you asked. After that you can parse the array and execute your `sql queries`.